# NLTK Perceptron Tagger - What does it recognize as FW (foreign word)?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, pos-tagger, perceptron

Relatively new to NLP and working on tagging sentences that contain foreign words using NLTK's PerceptronTagger (in Python) - but it continues to tag the tokenized foreign word by position in the syntax rather than as a 'FW'.

Does the whole sentence have to be in the language (with the appropriate language pickle file loaded) for the 'FW' tag to work ala the [NLTK documentation](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/tag.html)? Is there a way of sensing a foreign word within an English sentence?

On the flip side of that coin, do sentences containing foreign words that have been normalized into the English language tag as English? (ie: entrepreneur, siesta, zeitgeist, etc)

Answer (score 0):

in Spacy it means "Foreign Word". Maybe it is the same in NLTK.